# How to sum 1+2^2+3^3+...n^n in pascal?

Tags: sum, pascal

I want to sum that thing but only use the 'for loop' (no power functions). I've already created a loop that generates powers:

```
Program powers;
Var 
  i, n, result : integer;
  writeln('enter N'), read(n);
BEGIN
  Result := 1;

  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    Result := Result * n;
  end;

  writeln('result=',result);    
END.
```

But I neither have any idea on how to make that code generate multiple powers ( this code only generates n^n) nor how to make a loop that sums them together.

Comment: Instead of `Result := Result * n;` try `Result := Result + (i*i)`, oh, and set `Result` to zero initially.

Comment: This only sums squares?

Comment: Yes, did you try it?

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but this isn't actually my problem mate. I mean what I want to create a sum program for is: 1+ 2^2 + 3^3 + 4^4+ ...n^n

Comment: No offense taken - this is indeed what my suggestion would calculate. If you disagree, please give an example `N` with the expected result.

Comment: If we use n=3, the expected result should be 1+4+27=32, But in the program, the result is 14.

Comment: oh, you're right - my bad - sorry for being dense. It's not a sum of squares of i but rather a sum of i to the power of i that you're after - so you'll need a nested loop to calculate the power.

Comment: No problem sir. As I said before, I've already figured out a code to generate a particular N^N. But I can't give it an upgrade so it can generate all (N^N)s where N is 1--> given N

Comment: If you do not mind, can you help me with that sir? I've been trying to make this loop the whole day!

Comment: In Extended Pascal (ISO standard 10206) there is the integer power operator `pow` so you can write `result := result + n pow n;`. I am not sure, though, whether this meets your “no power functions” requirement, because an operator is kind of a special case of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I finally understand what you're asking, please try this:

```
Program powers;
Var 
  i, j, n, p, result : integer;

BEGIN
  write('enter N:');
  readln(n);
  Result := 0;

  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    p := 1;

    for j := 1 to i do
      p := p * i;

    Result := Result + p;
  end;

  writeln('result=', result);
END.
```

Comment: This idea has been spinning in my head for a while but I couldn't make it alive. Please accept my deepest thanks. Also, the following might sound stupid for you, but could you tell me how hard coding this can be for a newbie like me? To be more detailed, I neither knew I can put a loop under another one- although I thought about it- nor the 'J' which you used in the 'for loop' can play two roles at the same time. And as I said, the idea of the code was already in my head. I would be grateful if you could answer this question for me.

Comment: Well, it can be hard to come up with a solution to a problem that you haven't seen before, but as time goes by, and you get more experienced, more and more problems will look kind of similar to things that you've done before, so you can base new solutions on patterns that you've used prior. Bottom line: it gets easier over time - there were definitely many concepts that I had a hard time getting my head around when I started out - it still happens from time to time.

Comment: Thanks for the support sir. I appreciate your time (:

Answer (score 1):

It's best to break problems down into smaller problems. In this case, you may wish to have a `pow` function to handle the exponentiation for you.

*Hopefully the `pow` function is acceptable if it's not a **library** function.*

```
  function pow(n, exp : integer) : integer;
  var
    i, result : integer;
  begin
    result := n;

    for i := 2 to exp do
      result := result * n;

    pow := result;
  end;
```

Then the main portion of your program is simpler.

```
program powers;
var
  n, i, sum : integer;

  function pow(n, exp : integer) : integer;
  var
    i, result : integer;
  begin
    result := n;

    for i := 2 to exp do
      result := result * n;

    pow := result;
  end;
begin
  sum := 0;

  write('enter N:');
  readln(n);

  for i := 0 to n do
    sum := sum + pow(i, i);

  writeln('result=', sum);
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The problem was originally given by my teacher, so this would be funny (because he doesn't want us to use the power funtion).

Comment: Your teacher should be encouraging you to break problems down into smaller problems. I can understand them wanting you to not use library functions, though. Reinventing the wheel is foolhardy from a pragmatic standpoint, but can be very useful when learning.

Comment: Additionally, if you find this answer useful, you can upvote and accept it and any other useful answers.